# Combine List and Radio Buttons and Section

Tags: android, radio-button

First of all I'm totally new into Android thing so my biggest problem is to choose the right components. But, work must be done and with your help I will learn how :)

I need to have two section titles, 4 items and radio selector but with green checkmarks not standard radio button.

First for Items are always there, not scrollable, and each opens additional menu to save some settings.

Radio then also give one of three options that is saved when Button is clicked.

I have no clue how to start, should I implement fragments or set it in listview, or just in linear layout.

Specially because of sections, as far as I've read, having sections means lot of code?

Here is a photo, so please advise.

Tnx. [image: InfoImage]

Comment: please clearly mention what is your problem ? are you unable to implement radio button ?

Comment: No, I have no clue how to set the whole activity. I now how to do the scroll list, I know how to have radio buttons, but how to add sections and connect two of those into one action, there is where I'm struggling. Question is should I use fragments? do I need to use complicated list view for 4 Items and sections, or can I "draw" them somehow in some easier way?